# GeckoDriver Selenium 3.4 - FF issue, WebDriverException handlers time out

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

Recently we upgraded our Selenium C# binding , v3.4 and we are start using the Gecko Driver  which is for FF support, so we are using v 0.16.1, 
We notice that after click that open new window (FF) we got WebDriverException handlers time out, pops from : driver.WindowHandles (Selenium command),

We are wondering if it is common issue or if you know how to workaround that issue?

Init Driver Code:

```
public void Setup()
{
  var driverService = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
  driverService.FirefoxBinaryPath = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla    Firefox\firefox.exe";
  driverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
  driverService.SuppressInitialDiagnosticInformation = true;
  m_driver = new FirefoxDriver(driverService, new FirefoxOptions(),    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation [here](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) to work with geckodriver v0.16.0 you need to bump up your Selenium version to 3.4.0. So it essentially means to work with geckodriver v0.16.1 Selenium 3.4.0 is mandatory.

`Note that geckodriver v0.16.0 is only compatible with Selenium 3.4 and greater.`

Comment: Sorry it is typo mistake, we are using 3.4.0

Comment: Can you please format your code for a better view? Let us know the Selenium binding you are using & update the error stacktrace within the Question as well. Thanks

Comment: 'The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:56195/session/c2c37bf7-7001-41dc-8a5a-75b7f6b60233/window/handles timed out after 60 seconds.'

Comment: Selenium C# binding

Comment: Stack trace : 'HttpCommandExecutor.cs:line 121
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.DriverServiceCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute) in c:\Projects\webdriver\dotnet\src\webdriver\Remote\DriverServiceCommandExecutor.cs:line 84
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters) in c:\Projects\webdriver\dotnet\src\webdriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver.cs:line 1177
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.get_WindowHandles() in c:\Projects\webdriver\dotnet\src\webdriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver.cs'

Comment: `timed out after 60 seconds` is pretty much expected as you mentioned `TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60)` in your code. Can you sum up exactly what are you trying to do through your code?

Comment: I tried to see if there any new handler that added to driver as indication of a new window , then to add it to dictionary and switch to new window, so basically the command that generate the exception is :  driver.WindowHandles (Selenium Command) , the code is not the issue here but the Selenium command (WebDriver)